# How do I fill a polygon made up of randomized points in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

currently for a project i have a list variable containing 36 (x,y) coordinates. The intent is to draw a polygon that's inside is filled. all of the points are randomized but limited to a large square around the border of the screen so there will always be a border of points. When i use the pygame.draw.polygon command. It seems no matter how many different random points are generated the polygon that comes out is always messed up with lots of holes in the center and triangle like shapes that form, just not a filled shape.

Are there some kind of rules with using the draw.polygon command that i don't understand?

does the amount of points i use negatively effect the shape?

why is it that i am making a closed shape but it is not filling all the way?

Are their alternative methods to make a filled polygon also?

Thanks for your help and time.

(picture is rotated look at mouse direction)
[image: picture of points enlarged(rotated look at mouse position)]

[image]
This picture is right side up

My main question is why the polygon isnt filling entirely and why the bottom never attaches all the way.
See the code below:

```
def build(self):  
    for i in range(1,5):  
        for b in range(1,7):  
            if i == 1:  
                x = R.randrange(b*100,b*1000)  
                y = R.randrange(0,1000)  
                points.append([x,y])  
            elif i == 2:  
                x = R.randrange(9000,10000)  
                y = R.randrange(b*1000-1000,b*1000)  
                points.append([x,y])  
            elif i == 3:  
                x = R.randrange(b*1000,b*1000+1000)  
                y = R.randrange(9000,10000)  
                points.append([x,y])  
            elif i == 4 and b!=9:  
                x = R.randrange(0,1000)  
                y = R.randrange(b*1000-1000,b*1000)  
                points.append([x,y])
```

this is my func to make the points

```
    screen.fill(blue)

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,green,(points))
```

draw statement

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should show some coordinates that you tried. Polygon is a complicated object. There are too many coordinates included. So if there is any gap or hole, it's probably about weird coordinates that you wrote.

Comment: The order of the coordinates matters. If all your coordinates are totally randomized, it's no suprise the polygon is messed up. Just for fun, look at a bunch of your randomized coordinates that results in a messed up polygon, and try to draw it on a sheet of paper.

Comment: I will add a illustration if a few hours i was planning on it but I was short in time

Comment: The cordinates are in order not random

Comment: Then could you please post a minimal, executable program that shows your issue? Otherwise, it is hard to answer your question

Comment: pictures added for better visual

Comment: my main  question is why the shape gets divided in half if the points connected by nearest point that shouldn't happen

Comment: Do it with a smaller set and see if you can control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are two issues.

The first issue is causing the mess at the top of the image. There is an error in this line in the case where `i == 1`:

```
x = R.randrange(b*100,b*1000)
```

This selects an `x` value each time through the loop, but the selections are from overlapping ranges, rather than strictly increasing ones. I suspect you wanted to use the logic more like the `i == 3` case:

```
x = R.randrange(b*1000,b*1000+1000)
```

The second issue is more of a logic issue. You're `i == 1` and `i == 2` cases describe the top and right edges of your shape with increasing `x` and `y` values, respectively. Your `i == 3` and `i == 4` cases describe the bottom and left side, but they also are described with increasing `x` and `y` values. This breaks the connections between the corners of the polygon, and is responsible for the reversed colors and the long diagonal line (between the end of the bottom edge and the start of the left edge).

Here's my suggested solution, which generalizes your code a bit. Rather than looping on a meaningless `i` number and using `if` statements to handle the different edges, I describe each edge by a 4-tuple of values (the starting x and y values, and the offsets for each successive point) and loop over a list of tuples. The loop body is very simple, as an additional random offset is added to each coordinate as it is calculated:

```
for x, dx, y, dy in [(0,1000, 0, 0), (9000, 0, 0, 1000),
                     (9000, -1000, 9000, 0), (0, 0, 9000, -1000)]:
    for b in range(9):
        points.append([x + b*dx + R.randrange(1000), y + b*dy + R.randrange(1000)])
```

I don't currently have a working PyGame install so I haven't been able to verify that this will draw exactly right as a polygon, but it should at least get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much blckknght it works. I truely appriciate your time and what you do on here